# XMLReader issues while parse XML Object

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I'm trying to use XMLReader from [XMLReader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader) to apply in my project. 
But I face to to an issue, that I can't fix this bug. Here is my implementation. I design an architecture for it included processes and task. Each process has individual tasks connect together. Right here is transform task, which receive an GDataXMlDocument from previous task to handle next.

```
ResponseMessage* response = [super execute:request];
    // To do task here
    //
    GDataXMLDocument *docObject = [[request getMessage:@"documentObject"] messageData];
    NSString *content = [[docObject rootElement] XMLString];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[docObject rootElement] XMLString]);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dictionaryXML = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:[[docObject rootElement] XMLString] error:&error];
```

And small part of XML object:

```
<IposDocument xmlns="http://www.csc.com/integral/ipos-common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ipos-prospect="http://www.csc.com/integral/ipos-prospect"><Header><DocType/><DocId/><Version/><Validate/><IsValidateSuccess/><ClientDate/></Header><Data><ipos-prospect:Prospect vpms-suffix="Prospect"><ipos-prospect:Person vpms-suffix="Person"><ipos-prospect:FirstName vpms-suffix="FirstName" visible="1" mandatory="1" editable="1" default="" validate="" prefix="prospect.person.firstName."/><ipos-prospect:MiddleName vpms-suffix="MiddleName" visible="1" mandatory="0" editable="1" default="" validate="" prefix="prospect.person.middleName."/>
```

But XMLReader can't parse this object and always return nil. I don't know why althought debug it a dozen times. Any help is appreciate. Thank you very much.

Comment: Print out your error and see what the error says.

Comment: Unfortunately! There's no error, XMLReader use NSXMLParser for xml parsing. And you know, parse function of NSXMLParser return BOOL. It returns NO! That why it can convert to NSDictionary at the end!

Comment: Yea, but you're passing in an error pointer -- your error object should have data if an error occurred (via the delegate method in NSXMLParser) -- so, what appears on your console if you do `NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);` after `NSDictionary *dictionaryXML = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:[[docObject rootElement] XMLString] error:&error];` ?

Comment: Also, can you show the XML you're feeding in?

Comment: Yup! I tried! But it returns nil:
2014-12-09 17:56:53.959 iPOS[5116:70b] Error: (null)

Comment: @KerrM: I updated with content of xml object, just a small part!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66465/discussion-between-kerrm-and-phong-nguyen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your XML is invalid. [This](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) document defines XML in its entirety. There are [tools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) [online](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/) to help you validate your XML files.